# Some easy book or material introducing optimal stopping

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-calculus, book-recommendation, stochastic-differential-equations

I am now reading Chapter 10 in Oksendal's book (Application to Optimal Stopping), but I found it very hard to understand (I am a PDE student). Is there any other good book or material introducing optimal stopping? Thank you so much!

Comment: I'd like to know what are you struggling to understand, so I looked up the chapter. Are the proofs hard to understand, or is it hard to understand the motivations behind the chapters? Or is it hard to understand certain parts of certain proofs? If you are a PDE student, then you will have connected the dots : the characteristic operator as a PDE operator connects well with the optimal stopping problem , from the given characterisations.

Comment: Actually, I am fine with most of the proof and understand the motivation of having the optimal stopping. However I find it difficult to deal with the exercise. For example, in some case, if the reward function is $g$ and it satisfies $E^x[g(X_t)] < g(x)$, then the optimal reward is $g$.

Comment: Oh so you've got a problem with an exercise! Barely anybody's seen your question : if you want you can modify your question here and I can help you add the context and so on (basically, you've got a problem in Oksendal SDE chapter 10, should be good enough once you state the question). Till then, I will see the exercise.

Comment: Or if there's more than one exercise and we can't modify the question as it stands, then I'll use the comments to help you find the "key" steps that you can use to solve these problems. I know Oksendal, the book can be unforgiving at times, with all kinds of convoluted notation, skipped steps, what not!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! But I am stuck in many exercise, so I am looking for other book, see if I can solve the problem by myself. To be honest, I even do not know how to get 10.1. I think 10.1a to 10.1c can be handled by direct computations. But I am in doubt about 10.1d.

Comment: Also, I guess the optimal reward solves the equation generated by the random variable $X_t$ under some suitable conditions. But I can not find some reference for it.